# Filter grouped data with specific column value

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter grouped data with specific column value but with missing value. For example, `id=2` have only `No` value, `id=5` and `id=7` have `No` but there are `NA` values. I need only these three Ids.

```r
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7),
                 cate=c('Yes',NA,NA,'Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','No','No','No','No','Yes','Yes',
                        'No','No','Yes','Yes','No',NA,'No','Yes','No',NA,NA,'No'))
```

I expected

```
     id cate 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     2 No   
2     2 No  
3     5 No
4     5 NA
5     7 No
6     7 NA
7     7 NA
8     7 No
```

I try with

```
librrary(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(all(cate == 'No'))
```

but not select id 5 and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `na.rm = TRUE` into `all()` to allow `NA` in each ID.

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(cate == 'No', na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 × 2
#      id cate 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     2 No   
# 2     2 No   
# 3     5 No   
# 4     5 NA   
# 5     7 No   
# 6     7 NA   
# 7     7 NA   
# 8     7 No
```

Answer (score 2):

The `all()` function will only return ids in your group by where ALL values in cate, per id, meet the condition, cate == 'No'. id=7 has some NAs so the `all()` function won't return id=7.

This will return ids if their values are either 'No' OR NA:

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(all(cate== 'No'|is.na(cate)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id cate 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     2 No   
2     2 No   
3     5 No   
4     5 NA   
5     7 No   
6     7 NA   
7     7 NA   
8     7 No
```

Answer (score 2):

`base` R option using `ave` with `all` like this:

```r
df2[with(df2, ave((cate== 'No'|is.na(cate)), id, FUN = all)), ]
#>    id cate
#> 8   2   No
#> 9   2   No
#> 18  5   No
#> 19  5 <NA>
#> 22  7   No
#> 23  7 <NA>
#> 24  7 <NA>
#> 25  7   No
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>